# To prove something is a functor isn't it enough to prove that it commutes with composition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, category-theory

The second thing you usually have to prove is that $F(\text{id}_X) = \text{id}_{FX}$ for all $X \in C$, where $F: C \to C'$ is the supposed functor.

I think it's enough to just prove that $F$ commutes with composition, or $F(g\circ f) = F(g) \circ F(f), \ \forall f: X\to Y, g : Y \to Z$ in $C$.

Proof: if $F$ commutes with composition in $C$, then for all $X \in C, \ f : X \to Y \in \text{Mor}(C)$, we have $F(f) = F(f \circ \text{id}_X) = F(f) \circ F(\text{id}_X)$, but the identity in $\text{Hom}_{C'}(FX, FX)$ is unique, so $F(\text{id}_X) = \text{id}_{FX}$ necessarily.

Is that correct?

Comment: This would make my category theory problem set a whole lot easier if true.   *Please be true*.

Comment: If $F$ is not full, then you may not have $g=g\circ Fid_X$ on the entire hom-set so the second condition is necessary.

Comment: The property of the identity morphism is $id \circ f = f$ for *all* $f$ and similarly for the other side.  As you say, a morphism with that property is unique if it exists.  Unfortunately, not every morphism $f$ needs to be of the form $F(f)$, so you can't apply the uniqueness result.

Comment: @Chilango, so if $F$ is a full functor, ie each hom-set mapping is surjective, then proving commutation with composition is enough in that case?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: you have $f:x\to y;\ x,y \in C$ and you want to prove that if $g:z\to w;\ z,w\in C'$, then $g\circ Fid_z=g$. If $F$ is full then what does this say about $g$? And then?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Sorry, I wrote something wrong in a comment. If $F$ is full, then it's enough.

Comment: @Oskar: fullness is enough: $g\circ Fid_z=Ff\circ Fid_z=F(f\circ id_z)=Ff=g$

Comment: @Chilango Yes, I have already pointed it out. Sorry for that :)

Comment: But I should notice (I made a mistake because I forgot it), that to prove that $F(\text{id}_X)$ is an identity it's enough to check that $g\circ F(\text{id}_X)=g$ only for all $g\colon F(X)\to F(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a concrete counter-example.  Every [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) (set with a associative binary operation with left and right unit, i.e. a group without inverses) gives rise to a category: pick something arbitrary for the single object and have the hom-set be the elements of the monoid, composition be the multiplication, and the identity be the unit of the monoid.  A functor between such categories is then a monoid homomorphism. Your question is then: is a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) homomorphism automatically a monoid homomorphism?  A semigroup being like a monoid but without a unit.

The answer is "no". The powerset of a singleton set, $\mathcal{P}(1)$, is a monoid with binary operation union and unit $\{\}$.   Let $f : \mathcal{P}(1) \to \mathcal{P}(1)$ defined by $f(s) = 1$. Then $1 = f(s\cup t) = f(s)\cup f(t) = 1 \cup 1 = 1$, so it is a semigroup homomorphism, but $f(\{\}) = 1 \neq \{\}$, so it is not a monoid homomorphism.

That said, every *surjective* semigroup homomorphism is a monoid homomorphism.  This proves that every full functor automatically preserves identities if it preserves composition.